# GoCD deploying to Crashlytics Android and IOS

Tags: mobile, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, continuous-delivery, go-cd

Someone knows, how can I use [GoCD](https://www.gocd.io/) to deploying version to [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/)(Fabric)?

Answer (score 2):

I used a [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) script to upload apk.

FastlaneFile - inside Android Project directory

```
platform :android do 
  lane :crashlytics do | options |
    gradle(task: ("assembleRelease"+options[:build]))
    crashlytics(
      api_token: "xxxxxxxxx",
      build_secret: "xxxxxxxxx",
      notes: loadReleaseNotesCrashlytics()
    )
  end
  def loadReleaseNotesCrashlytics()
    file = File.open("../crashlytics/release_note.txt", "r")
    data = file.read
    file.close
    return data
  end
end
```

Afterward I put inside a job GOCD executing script, using Environment Variable with Fastlane path on CI server. And I have success.

```
-c
#{fastlane} crashlytics build:Release
```